# Display "Sold Out" text on External products with empty price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

Some Amazon imported products dont have price or are sold out but not removed from listings, and its breaking aligments.

Im trying to customize `woocommerce/templates/loop/price.php`template file.

From this

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To something like this

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : 
    if (empty($price)) 
    { 
        echo '<a href="link">Sold Out</a>';} 
    else 
    { ?>
        <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
    <?php }; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But its not working properly as now all products are sold out.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code instead of overriding price template. The code will make sure that the product is external and the price is zero or empty.

```
function op_change_price_html( $price_html, $product ) {
   if ( 'external' === $product->get_type() && empty( $product->get_price() ) ) {
       return 'Sold Out';
   }
   return $price_html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_empty_price_html', 'op_change_price_html', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'op_change_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you works like a charm, for some reason overriding template file didn't work, but your solution  works grate over all templates even in back-end. thanx

Comment: Glad to hear that :)